# How to convert all links to no follow links of particlular section of a webpage

Tags: links

I just wanna convert all links to no follow links which are being displayed in sidebar or footer or comments.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_rel_nofollow()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_rel_nofollow) does this for you. It is already called on `pre_comment_content`, so comments should be covered. For sidebars and footers, this depends on the widgets and other code you use there, but it should be possible to call that function there too.

Comment: is this filter applied by default? or do i need to apply it.

Comment: @articlestack: It is applied to comments (via the `pre_comment_content` filter) in [`default-filters.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L168), so that should be OK. For the sidebars you should do this yourself, unless you use a widget that already does this.